# Core Data NSPredicate to filter results

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject that contains a bID and a pID. Within the set of NSManagedObjects, I only want a subset returned and I'm struggling to find the correct NSPredicate or way to get what I need out of Core Data.

Here's my full list:

bid   pid
41    0
42    41
43    0
44    0
47    41
48    0
49    0
50    43

There is a parent-child relationship above.

Rules:

If a record's PID = 0, it means that that record IS a parent record. 
If a record's PID != 0, then that record's PID refers to it's parent record's BID.

Example:

1) BID = 41 is a parent record. Why? Because records BID=42 and record BID=47 have PID's of 41, meaning those are children of its PID record.
2) BID = 42 has a parent record with a BID = 41.
3) BID = 43 is a parent record.
4) BID = 44 is a parent record.
5) BID = 47 has a parent record with a BID = 41 because its PID = 41. See #1 above.
6) BID = 48 is a parent record.
7) BID = 49 is a parent record.
8) BID = 50 is a child record, and its parent record has a BID = 43.

See the pattern?

Now, basically from that, I want only the following rows fetched:

bid   pid
44    0
47    41
48    0
49    0
50    43

BID = 41, BID = 48, BID = 49 should all be returned because there are no records with a PID equal to their BID.

BID = 47 should be returned because it is the most recent child of PID = 41.
BID = 50 should be returned because it is the most recent child of PID = 43.

Hope this helps explain it more.

Comment: oops, even after you modified the question, it does not seem to be clear what you want to get from the data. Try to define a rule to fetch your data and you will see how to do it. With your explaination here, I don't see any rule to fetch the data you want. You said you want to get bid=44, but later on, you said 41?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, this is pretty easy, you just need to set the predicate of bid >= 43.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bid >= %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:43]];
```

I guess maybe you are having problem with the NSNumber, because Core Data saves many types under the NSNumber, includes: int, BOOL, etc... [See here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-DontLinkElementID_9)

Comment: Ok, in the data set I gave you, that just so happens to be the case. But that won't work for a larger set of data. 

Its a parent-child relationship. PID refers to another BID. So BID of 41 has 2 children, BID=42 and BID=47. Of that relationship, I only want the BID=47 returned. If the PID is 0, then add that to the subset as well, as long as there are no rows w/ a PID = BID.

Comment: I think you should spend some more times to describe exactly what you want to do by editing the question clearly and if possible, give us some rules, otherwise, the answer would be useless.

Comment: you may want to publish your data models somewhere as well.